# Evaluate limit of a sequence... NBHM $2013$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Question is to Evaluate $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sin((2n\pi + \frac{1}{2n\pi}) \sin(2n\pi + \frac{1}{2n\pi}))$$

All I could do was to see that $$\sin(2n\pi + \frac{1}{2n\pi}))=\sin( \frac{1}{2n\pi})$$

Just because $\sin(2n\pi+\theta)=\sin(\theta)$..

So, we now have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sin((2n\pi + \frac{1}{2n\pi}) \sin( \frac{1}{2n\pi}))$$

Now, as $\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty}x\sin(\frac{1}{x})=1$ we would have 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}2n\pi \sin( \frac{1}{2n\pi})=1$$

So, we now have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sin(1 + \frac{1}{2n\pi} \sin( \frac{1}{2n\pi}))$$

Now, as $\sin(x)$ is bounded and $\frac{1}{2n\pi} \rightarrow 0$ we would have

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2n\pi} \sin( \frac{1}{2n\pi})=0$$

So, we would now left with :

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sin(1)=\sin(1)$$

After all i would like to say that as $\sin (x)$ is continuous I can take limits inside.

So, we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sin((2n\pi + \frac{1}{2n\pi}) \sin(2n\pi + \frac{1}{2n\pi}))=\sin 1$$

I would like somebody to check if I have done correctly and I would be thankful if any body can let me know if there is anything more to be specified to do so.

Thank you... :)

Comment: I am not seeing here any mistake

Comment: This is in NBHM 2013 Ph.D exam question paper...

Comment: I did not see your heading first

Comment: It is alright :) I have kept it just for my quick reference.... :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: really, this is a Ph.D. exam question? Seems pretty basic for that.

Comment: In any exam there would be one simple question at least and this is of such kind :)

Comment: @Samprity : If there are any entrance exam questions in your posts Would you mind to edit with NBHM/TIFR/CSIR titles? That would be helpful (at least for me :D)

Comment: All of this seems to be correct. I checked numerically and the terms converge quite quickly

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, one question : $\sin(2n\pi+x)=\sin x$ if $n$ is an integer. But here $n$ is only real, right?

Comment: @Bhattacharjee Here $n$ is considered only an integer

Comment: @Koushik I shall try as much as possible, at least from the next time I shall post with the source. There are 15 to 20 questions in my account. There are also some question at Srity mallik's account. Should we gather them all under a tag "Indian Entrace Examination" ?

Comment: @Samprity : that would be great then.... :) please let me know what all i can do :)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee : that $n$ is actually natural number sequence.... Thank you for your interest :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici : Thank you so much for your interest :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Well, your answer looks good. One can also use $\sin(A+B)$ formula and do this problem. This problem is actually an hint to the follow up problem on uniformly continuity asked in the same question paper. This is one of the reasons as to why the function $f(x)= \sin(x\cdot \sin(x))$ fails to be uniformly continuous :)

Comment: @Chandrasekhar : I am lad that you like my idea.. coming to $f(x)=\sin(x.\sin x)$ at present i do not have any idea but as you said i will try doing that and post the question if i have some doubt... Thank you :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Consider $x_{n}=2n\pi + \frac{1}{2n\pi}$ and $y_{n}=2n\pi$. Note that $|x_{n}-y_{n}|\to 0$ where as $|f(x_{n})-f(y_{n})| \to 1$.

Comment: @Chandrasekhar : But I am not familiar with such criterion of uniform continuity.. I would work on that.. thank you :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Please write down the answer of your question. Duplicate question of it are coming which can not be closed as it has no answer.

Comment: @HopelessFool : I do not know what to write as an answer... :O should i just copy paste what i have written? I believe it should have been explained better...There might be some better explanation from somebody else.. or should i just delete this so that the other question would become original one :D

Comment: Have you seen the linked question to it? Jock.

Comment: @HopelessFool : I do not see any linked question for this question :O anyways i have typed the same thing and posted it as an answer and accepted it... hope it is fine now!

Comment: We know that $\sin(2n\pi+\theta)=\sin\theta$ only for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. But, let $a=\lim_{n\to\infty}n$. We cannot say that $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, so can you explain how $\sin(2n\pi+\frac{1}{2n\pi})=\sin\frac{1}{2n\pi}$

Comment: @Mathematician171 : I am taking limit after concluding $\sin(2n\pi+\frac{1}{2n\pi})=\sin\frac{1}{2n\pi}$.. So, taking limits should not be a problemm

Comment: Let $\theta=\frac{1}{2n\pi}$. We know that $\sin(2n\pi+\theta)=\sin{\theta}$ only for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, but in this case $n\notin\mathbb{Z}$ because $n\to\infty$. This is the same as we say that $\sin(2a\pi+b)=\sin{b}$ for $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and $b=\frac{\pi}{6}$. In this case $LHS=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $RHS=\frac{1}{2}$, so it isn't true because $a\notin\mathbb{Z}$. From this we can see that $\sin(2n\pi+\theta)=\sin\theta$ isn't true for all $n\in\mathbb{R}$ because $n$ must be an integer. Here $n$ isn't an integer, so can you explain how $\sin(2n\pi+\theta)=\sin\theta$ or tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Mathematician171 : No... I am not taking arbitrary sequence, i am taking only integer sequence when i say $n\rightarrow \infty$ I mean it goes like $1,2,3,\cdots$ and not like $\frac{1}{2}+1,\frac{1}{2}+2,\cdots\frac{2n+1}{2},\cdots$... Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is to Evaluate $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sin((2n\pi + \frac{1}{2n\pi}) \sin(2n\pi + \frac{1}{2n\pi}))$$

As $\sin(2n\pi+\theta)=\sin(\theta)$ we would have :

$$\sin(2n\pi + \frac{1}{2n\pi}))=\sin( \frac{1}{2n\pi})$$

So, we now have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sin((2n\pi + \frac{1}{2n\pi}) \sin( \frac{1}{2n\pi}))$$

Now, as $\lim _{x\rightarrow \infty}x\sin(\frac{1}{x})=1$ we would have 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}2n\pi \sin( \frac{1}{2n\pi})=1$$

So, we now have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sin(1 + \frac{1}{2n\pi} \sin( \frac{1}{2n\pi}))$$

Now, as $\sin(x)$ is bounded and $\frac{1}{2n\pi} \rightarrow 0$ we would have

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2n\pi} \sin( \frac{1}{2n\pi})=0$$

So, we would now left with :

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sin(1)=\sin(1)$$

After all i would like to say that as $\sin (x)$ is continuous I can take limits inside.

So, we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sin((2n\pi + \frac{1}{2n\pi}) \sin(2n\pi + \frac{1}{2n\pi}))=\sin 1$$